# How to access Switch argument inside a case in Dart

Tags: if-statement, types, dart, flutter, switch-statement

I want to switch on animals and take the appropriate action.

```
switch (animal.runtimeType) {
  case Cat:
    animal.pet();
    break;
  case Crocodile:
    animal.runAway();
    break;
  default:
    print('Not a known animal.');
}
```

If I were if-chaining this would work, since the scope would know the type of `animal` in the `if (animal is Cat){}` block.

For some reason this is not the case with switch statements.
In this case I will get the error

`The method pet() isn't defined for the class animal`

How can I use the case assertion in the case block?
I cant use `as` since my CI Lint won't allow it (which is a good thing) and it makes no sense to use an If operation inside the case, since using a if-else statement would be less code and offer more usability.

Comment: i feel your pain, C# can do that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I did not understand your question or you did not understand the problem.

Assuming you defined the method `pet()` inside `Cat`, but not inside `Animal`, the error `The method pet() isn't defined for the class animal` happens because `Animal` is generic. An `Animal` is not necessarily a `Cat`, so you cannot call the method `pet()` for `Animal`, since it's defined only inside `Cat`.

If `animal` is a local variable, it's totally safe to cast inside the case block. You can reliably do `(animal as Cat).pet();`, once you just checked that `animal` is indeed a `Cat`.

Comment: So why would `animal` inside of the case `Cat` need to be typecast when the same is not necessary in the if-block? 
The compiler should know the state of animal in any given case and there should be no need to check it again.
Unless the scope of the if-case is local (and the value cannot change) and the switch case is global (and the value might change before the block returns).

Comment: @JoelBroström About that, I'm having trouble following your example. Regardless of whether I make `animal` be a `Cat` or just an `Animal`, it fails the switch cases and falls to default: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0bf1a2bd12405039c10b0fe1beacccee

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, an updated example would be very helpful in understanding your issue.

Comment: @JoelBroström  Because those are different usages. Your switch is not the same as `if (animal is Cat) {}`, it is the same as `if (animal.runtimeType == Cat) {}`. Dart is able to autocast only when you use `is`.

Comment: @HugoPassos And I cannot use `is` in a switch case since it only handels `==` comparisons?
Coming from Kotlin a When statement seam like an improvement on the Dart switch statement in every aspects.
Am I wrong?

Comment: @JoshuaWade I should have stated it was only pseudo code for illustrating my problem. Basically what I want to understand is how the scope of switch and if statements differ, or how I can get the same behaviour in a switch as in an if-else chain.

Comment: @JoelBroström You are correct. There's no way to do that in Dart, and I recommend you to lower your expectations. Kotlin is, in my opinion, the best programming language in the world, so you'll find in Dart dozens of limitations when comparing to Kotlin.

Comment: @JoshuaWade I tried your example and as you said it always go to default. Then I took the same code and run it in my editor (Android Studio) and it prints the correct answer ('pet'). I also added the elseif implementation, which looks much better and have better functionality. But using elseif when you have a set number of outcomes is to me architecturally wrong. Switches declare a fixed set of options while elseif is more flexible, but overkill.
Anyway here is your code modified with an elseif example.
If you have the time would you mind trying to run it locally in your dev environment?

Comment: @JoshuaWade https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0bf1a2bd12405039c10b0fe1beacccee

Comment: @HugoPassos Thanks for making me smile :)

Comment: @JoelBroström That's the same link I pasted... see https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-Guide for instructions on how to share things with DartPad.

Comment: @JoelBroström I just tried with my local environment and it worked like a charm. Dunno what's going on with DartPad.

Comment: @JoshuaWade Regarding why the typecast is needed: because `switch` is  a separate construct from `if-else` and features don't come for free.  It seems like it'd be a reasonable feature request if you're willing to [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/new). ([I'm surprised that `switch` even accepts `Type`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case).)